# Screenshot iOS simulator in the same way iPhone does it (but not save to desktop)

Tags: ios, simulator

Is it possible to take a screenshot on the iPhone simulator, not save to the desktop, but to the device? The same way when you press the home button and the power button on the device, and the thumbnail appears on the bottom left, and opening it brings this screen:

[image]

I'm asking because I'm working on a share extension. And you can trigger it from this screen (bottom left upload icon). I'm unable to use my device for the next hour or so, as I am currently updating Xcode, because my phone is not supported by it anymore (stupid me updated my phone) and I have to update my mac software to support Xcode

Comment: No wonder you have not replied to my email yet...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: how is this off topic?  the xcode simulator an integral part of iOS development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not at this time.